AttributeError: 'FlDataRecord' object has no attribute 'setfield'
I'm attempting to execute this Python code within SAP BODS, but I'm encountering the following error.
15320 13192 DQX-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM |Data flow New_DataFlow89|Transform Base_UserDefined
15320 13192 DQX-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM Transform <Base_UserDefined>: Traceback (most recent call last):
15320 13192 DQX-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM File "EXPRESSION", line 25, in <module>
15320 13192 DQX-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM AttributeError: 'FlDataRecord' object has no attribute 'setfield'.
15320 13192 DQX-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM |Data flow New_DataFlow89|Transform Base_UserDefined
15320 13192 DQX-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM Transform <Base_UserDefined>: <UDT0004>: Error executing the expression.
15320 13192 DQX-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM |Data flow New_DataFlow89|Transform Base_UserDefined
15320 13192 DQX-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM Transform <Base_UserDefined>: DLL <udt_transformu.dll> runtime function <ProcessCollection> failed with error <3>. More
15320 13192 DQX-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM detailed information may be obtained from previous errors.
0 0 RUN-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM
0 0 RUN-058306 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM
0 0 RUN-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM
0 0 RUN-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM |Data flow New_DataFlow89|Transform Base_UserDefined
15320 13192 RUN-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:06 AM
19784 25984 DQX-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:16 AM |Data flow New_DataFlow89|Transform Base_UserDefined
19784 25984 DQX-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:16 AM Transform <Base_UserDefined>: DLL <udt_transformu.dll> runtime function <ProcessCollection> failed with error <3>. More
19784 25984 DQX-058302 5/7/2024 7:00:16 AM detailed information may be obtained from previous errors.

This is my initial attempt at running Python code in BODS.
I use below Python code
import re

fieldVal = record.GetField(u'BASIC_DATA_TEXT')
material_descriptions = [fieldVal]
pattern = r"(\d+)\s*(\w+)/(\w+)"
results = []

for desc in material_descriptions:
    newrecord = DataManager.NewDataRecord(1)
    matches = re.findall(pattern,desc)
    unit_strings = []
    if matches:
        for match in matches:
            quantity, unit1, unit2 = match
            unit_string = f"{quantity} {unit1}/{unit2}"
            unit_strings.append(unit_string)
    
    if unit_strings:
        unit_info = ", ".join(unit_strings)
        record.setfield(u'Unit_Extract',u'unit_info')
        
        Collection.AddRecord(newrecord)```


